# Formula for graphing activity of a specific variable

Tags: c, math, graph

I am trying to figure out a function for recording activity of a value, but still with no success. I will describe everything as detailed as possible to make the comfort you may need to suggest the answer.

---

- I have the function `lineto(x, y)` that draws a line to x, y position
  and changes the offset to the same x, y.
- I have the function `moveto(x, y)` that moves the offset to x, y position.
- The initial coordinates of the area are x0:y0 which is the top left corner

---

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

i.e I specify `variable`, `minimum` and `maximum` and the function
draws a line to the current state of the value, where a full height line will be the maximum. Also assume that `height` is a variable that represents the height of the graph area (box).

---

What I have for now is this:

```
(((current/height)*(range.maximum/height))/height)));
```

..Which I think.. is a complete nonsense.

Comment: Try `(current/range.maximum)*height`

Comment: @AlterMann That always draws the maximum, even if the variable has a value of `1` and the maximum is `512`.. so I don't think it complies with the box's height.

Comment: Standard: `(value - minimum) * height / (maximum - minimum)`. First multiply, then divide.

Comment: Using `height = 100;  range.maximum = 512; current = 1;` you get `1/512*100 = 0,1953125` using `height = 100;  range.maximum = 512; current = 55;`  you get `55/512*100 = 10,7421875`, do you mean this?

Comment: Theoretically, this looks exactly like what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically need to translate the interval [minimum, maximum] to the interval [0, height].

Using math :

[minimum, maximum] (-minimum) ->

[0, maximum-minimum] (/(max-min)) ->

[0, 1] -> (* height)

So the formula to represent x from [min,max] space in [0,height] space is

```
 xNew = ( (x-minimum)/(maximum-minimum) )* height; // extra pharathesis for clarity
```

For your current variable you would have

```
 currentInBox = ( (current - minimum) / (maximum-minimum) ) * height
```

Comment: You seem to understand what I mean, thought the formula you provided me with, didn't work. Look at the answer I posted of my question so you can eventually see the difference.

Comment: Well, you are using to substract from the height of the box rather then add to the bottom of the box:) . If you take my formula and you replace current with maximum you will get the result as being "height" , which I thought was the indended behavior. In your formula , if your current is equal to range.maximum you get the result 0 , which is exactly opposed :) .

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out with this algorithm:

```
(((current-range.minimum)*height) / range.maximum-range.minimum)
```

I used my `topercent` function `partial * 100 / full` as a template.

Comment: This work as long as the minimum is `0` I am not sure of how it will work if it isn't.

Comment: It will work as long as minimum isn't equal or grater then maximum :).